# Chrome MediaRecorder is randomly generating corrupted video files

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

- Chrome: Version 96.0.4664.55 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- System: Mac Catalina 10.15.5

---

I am using this code to generate small stand alone videos from a MediaRecorder:

```
var mediaRecorder;
var chunks;

// call this function to start the process
function startRecording(stream) {
  chunks = [];

  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp8" });

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  };

  mediaRecorder.onstop = function () {
    actualChunks = chunks.splice(0, chunks.length);
    const blob = new Blob(actualChunks, { type: "video/webm; codecs=vp8" });
    uploadVideoPart(blob); // Upload to server
  };

  recordVideoChunk(stream);
};

function recordVideoChunk(stream) {
  mediaRecorder.start();

  setTimeout(function() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    recordVideoChunk(stream);
  }, 10000); // 10 seconds videos
}
```

The problem is that some of the files generated are considered corrupted by ffmpeg:

> ffmpeg -v error -i 03_video_part_1638535340218.webm -f null -

```
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

More info about the file:

```
> ffprobe 03_video_part_1638535340218.webm
ffprobe version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1_3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '03_video_part_1638535340218.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 1280x1236, SAR 1:1 DAR 320:309, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
```

The error doesn't happen always and not in all stand alone videos.

I was not able to reproduce the error using Firefox

I have tracked the error to the browser itself, creating links in the same page that I download and check through ffmpeg. So possible causes in the upload mechanism are eliminated. The file is corrupted from origin.

Looks like the error never happens in the first file.

##### Things I have tried

Using other codecs:

- "video/webm; codecs=vp9"
- "video/webm"

Comment: Sounds like a bug, and then you could [file an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry) - Note: doing so requires a Google/Gmail account.

Comment: I am investigating.. it looks to me that there is some kind of race condition :?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I moved the creation of the `MediaRecorder` instance to the recurrent function and now it is working properly:

```
var mediaRecorder;
var chunks;

// call this function to start the process
function startRecording(stream) {
  chunks = [];

  recordVideoChunk(stream);
};

function recordVideoChunk(stream) {
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp8" });

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  };

  mediaRecorder.onstop = function () {
    actualChunks = chunks.splice(0, chunks.length);
    const blob = new Blob(actualChunks, { type: "video/webm; codecs=vp8" });
    uploadVideoPart(blob); // Upload to server
  };

  mediaRecorder.start();

  setTimeout(function() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    recordVideoChunk(stream);
  }, 10000); // 10 seconds videos
}
```

I think there was some kind of race condition that made the event listeners (`ondataavailable` and `onstop`) to not be called in the proper order, or to have multiple calls... to be honest I don't know what is the real problem and if there is a better version of the code I can create that also works.

Answer (score 0):

Video file corruption happens when one or more `ondataavailable()` chunks get lost somehow.

In your code `actualChunks = chunks.splice(0, chunks.length);` is weird for two reasons.

1. `actualChunks` goes into global scope because it's undeclared. It could use a `const` declaration. That may account for your possible race condition.
2. It's unnecessary.  Just do this instead.

```js
const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: mediaRecorder.mimeType });
```

**Pro tip** use a good Javascript IDE. It will complain about undeclared variables and save your xxx neck.

Comment: "Video file corruption happens when one or more ondataavailable() chunks get lost somehow." is this normal? is this avoidable? if not, how to fix the blob?

Comment: Not normal, not at all. Avoidable, yes, see my answer or the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this problem I have found.

After the MediaRecorder has been stoped there are many chances it will generates corrupted videos if we try to start it again.

So the solution is to create a new one (with the same stream and mediaType):

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaRecorder.stream, { type: mediaRecorder.mimeType });
```

It doesn't look to me that is causing any performance issue, and the final concatenated video looks smooth.